# $M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} N \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for cyclic modules $M,N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

> Is it true that $M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} N \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (considering $\mathbb{Z}$  as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module) if $M,N$ are cyclic $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (i. e. generated by one element)?

I would say yes, since $M \otimes_\mathbb{Z} N$ seems to be cyclic as well while having infinitely many elements, thus being isomorphing to $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group and furthermore as a module.

Comment: What about $M=N =\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: If you assume no torsion then it is trivial since M and N are both isomorphic to the additive integers

Answer (score 3):

In general this is not true: for instance

that $\mathbb{Z}_p \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_q \cong \{ 0\}$ if $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Comment: I think there's no need to require $\;gcd(p,q)=1\;$ . The tensor product still isn't isomorphic with $\;\Bbb Z\;$ .

Comment: Yes you right :) this is just a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, by the *Chinese remainder theorem*,
$$\mathbf Z/m\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\simeq\mathbf Z/mn\mathbf Z $$
if $m\wedge n=1$, hence it is a *torsion* cyclic group.It is not even cyclic if $m\wedge n>1$, be cause it has no element of order $mn$.